# How to copy selectedtext from activecontrol textbox

Tags: c#

i want to ask that how can i copy the selected text of active control textbox.
i tried this but it gives me the whole text , not the selected text :

```
private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string str = ActiveControl.Text;
    }
```

and i didn't want to copy a text from a specific textbox , such as :

```
string str = textbox1.SelectedText;
```

i want to copy the Selected Text of any active control textbox with context Menu Strip

thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Your issue here is that `ActiveControl` returns a Control, but not all controls can have SelectedText, like for example buttons. You could check if the control returned by ActiveControl is (for example) a textbox, and if so cast it and retrieve the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TextBox activeTxtBox = ActiveControl as TextBox;
       if(activeTxtBox!= null)
       {
           string str = activeTxtBox.SelectedText;
       }
```

Comment: Or, using C#7 pattern matching, `if (ActiveControl is TextBox activeTextBox)…`